# Force user to use external mic on Android?

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I force the user to put an external MIC to use the app?
My product will be receiving some audio input from the 3.5mm jack, if that is not plugged in we will receive garbage data. How can I make a check to insure external MIC is connected through 3.5mm jack.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force your users to plug an external mic to use the app because this info is not available from the Android API.

The 3.5mm jack port on smartphones and tablets is for audio output. Most of devices don't have an audio input.